# Low-level serial interface for Linux OS (Manual RTS/CTS control etc.)?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I'm looking for a library that can create a very low-level `RS232` connection - I'm working with a device that uses the `RTS/DTR` pins as relay controls.

The library has to be compatible with **Ubuntu 12.04** (Multi-platform preferred) and **C/C++** support would be preferred.

Comment: You want to handle rs232 on the gpio level? A step higher level already exists in the Linux world, it is built-in functionality of the serial terminal devices (/dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttyUSB0 in most cases). Their interface is unchanged long, long ago so the compatibility won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt CTS is possible to control (at least on a Intel 8250, NS16550 UART, which is what you'd find in a PC or similar hardware designs), but RTS and DTR can be controlled by software. Have a look at this page, the post by Michael Griffin:

http://www.control.com/thread/1026231695

This article talks more about the functionality you would be using:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6226

Comment: I may have been mistaken, I think it does use RTS and DTR.